# Descriptor in nodeJS google-protobuf

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, grpc

Hello I am new with gRPC and ProtoBuf
I am trying to communicate from a microservice written with Go via grpc.
In some operation, to send a request, it is necessary that I set type the message when sending in the request. I read some sources in golang and python languages. This is how they determine the type of messages.

I have a namespace with TypedMessage name in typescript to keeping message type and message value :

```
export namespace TypedMessage {
    export type AsObject = {
        type: string,
        value: Uint8Array | string,
    }
}
```

I need to convert every message to this type, so I wrote such a function :

```
function toTypedMessage(message: proto.Message) {
  const typedMessage = new TypedMessage();
  typedMessage.setType("Its not complete");
  typedMessage.setValue(message.serializeBinary());
  return typedMessage;
}
```

I inspired this from the Python and Go resources :

Go :

```
func GetMessageType(message proto.Message) string {
  return string(message.ProtoReflect().Descriptor().FullName())
}


func ToTypedMessage(message proto.Message) *TypedMessage {
  if message == nil {
    return nil
  }
  settings, _ := proto.Marshal(message)
  return &TypedMessage{
    Type:  GetMessageType(message),
    Value: settings,
  }
}
```

Python :

```
class Message:
    def __new__(cls, message) -> TypedMessage:
        return TypedMessage(
            type=message.DESCRIPTOR.full_name,
            value=message.SerializeToString()
        )
```

My problem in this part is the function I wrote `typedMessage.setType("");`
As it is known, this value must be a string. According to Go and Python sources, a descriptor is needed to return the message to the proto name like `message.ProtoReflect().Descriptor().FullName()` in go and like `message.DESCRIPTOR.full_name` in python. But it seems that there is no such thing in nodeJS google-protobuf.
Is there another solution or not?

I saw different sources. But I could not solve the problem
Here someone also said this:

Unfortunately this is not supported.

Other languages embed a "descriptor" for the proto file in the generated code. The descriptor contains information about a message, its fields, and also the custom options, all in binary protobuf format. See descriptor.proto

The code to read the extension is generated. If you had a FieldDescriptor, you could read your FieldOption extension. But you don't have this descriptor in Javascript generated code.

There is a possible workaround: You can use protoc to dump a FileDescriptorSet for your .proto file (see --descriptor_set_out option). You can read this binary message using Javascript (proto.google.protobuf.FileDescriptorSet from google-protobuf), navigate to your message, to the field in question, and then read your extension data to get the custom option value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

google-protobuf for javascript/typescript does not support reflection for code size and information leakage reasons.

https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-javascript/issues/184#issuecomment-1885260397